# Perl class use a method of its parent

Tags: perl, class, inheritance

I have this perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use lib "/home/gdanko/test/perl";
use Main;

Plugins::Plug1::devices;
```

The module Main looks like this

```
package Main;

use lib "/home/gdanko/test/perl";
use Plugins::Plug1;
use DBI;

@ISA = ('Exporter');
@EXPORT = qw();
@EXPORT_OK = qw($dbh &load_devices);

our $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=/home/gdanko/test/mydb.db", "", "");

sub load_devices {
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM devices");
    $sth->execute;
    my $devices = $dbh->selectall_hashref($sth, "id");
    return $devices;
}
1;
```

The module Plug1 looks like this

```
package Plug1;

use lib "/home/gdanko/test/perl";
use Data::Dumper;
use Main qw(&load_devices);

@ISA = ('Exporter');
@EXPORT = ();
@EXPORT_OK = qw(&devices);

sub devices {
    print "module plug1\n";
    my $devices = Main::load_devices;
    print Dumper(\$devices->{maguro});
}
1;
```

When I execute Plugins::Plug::devices from the main script I get this in return:
gdanko@apollo:~/test$ ./script.pl
module plug1
$VAR1 = \undef;

How can I make the methods and variables in Main available to Plug1?

Answer (score 1):

You describe your module variously as `Plugins::Plug1`, `Plugins::Plug`, `Plug1` and `plug1`. You must be clear which it is, and a module `Plugins::Plug1` must be in a file named `Plugins/Plug1.pm` starting with the statement `package Plugins::Plug1`

It is unclear from your question what is going wrong. What should happen is that Perl will tell you `Plugins::Plug1::devices` doesn't exist,  because your `package` statement doesn't match. But it looks like you are saying that `Main::load_devices` is returning `undef` instead of a hash reference.

It looks like the subroutines are probably being called, and you need to debug them. Put some `print` statements in your code to see what is being called, but most of all you must `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every file. That will reveal many simple mistakes.

Also note that `Exporter` exports symbols from a module into the calling package, and is unnecessary if you intend always to call the subroutines with their fully-qualified names. If you use `Exporter` you can omit the package names from the calls

Answer (score 0):

`Plugins::Plug1` must declare that it "is a" `Main` (hint: Just like they both declare that they have an "is a" relationship to `Exporter`.) . Then the methods will be immediately available. However, you should read the perldoc on objects (start with [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html)) if you're asking how to make variables "visible" to subclasses. You can't and you *shouldn't*.

I take it you're thinking standard OO and the variables in the package represent members of the object. The most common implementation is a blessed hash, where the members are named values in the hash.

Comment: I want the subclass Plug1 to be able to use methods from Main which "uses" it.

Comment: Inheritance is irrelevant here because the packages aren't classes, and the subroutines aren't methods - they are simple package subroutines in different namespaces. Nothing at all needs to be put in place for fully-qualified subroutine calls like this, except that the subroutine being called must have been compiled beforehand

Comment: @Borodin, inheritance isn't irrelevant in a question about "class", "method" and "parent". The code just shows that the asker has little idea about Perl OO.

Comment: @Axeman: despite its subject line, the question has nothing to do with object-oriented programming. If you decide the question is wrong and the subject line is right then we are left with almost nothing to answer

Comment: @Borodin, except some pointers as to how inheritance and objects are done in Perl. `*Plugins::Plug1::{ keys %Main:: } = values %Main::;` will answer his question too, but not in a way that he will help him recognize the difference between his example code and the way he's thinking of it as indicated by both the *question* and the *tags*.

Comment: @Axeman: what you describe is simple symbol exporting, and again nothing to do with Perl objects or inheritance

Comment: @Borodin, "what [I] describe" *where*? If you mean the stash assignment in my last comment, then you completely missed the point of my including it. Whether you acknowledge it or not, there are *two* parts to answering his question. 1) his disconnect between his code and Perl OO and 2) getting it to "work" (as in "it does not work"). Getting thinks to "work" is not *design*, Object/Class decomposition *is*. Design is what is important in software, getting an undesigned hunk of code to "work" is secondary.